# Composer Packages conflict

Tags: symfony, package, composer-php

I'm installing a new package on composer and I'm receiving the following error when I try to run '**composer update**':

> [Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\RuntimeException]
>      The process
>   has been signaled with signal "11".

I have figured out that the new package is somehow conflicting with another package I already have installed. On their own, I am able to install either one, but when I try to install both of them together, I receive that error message.

The packages that are in conflict are (from composer.json):

> "laravel/cashier": "~2.0"
>  "thujohn/analytics": "dev-master"

How can I figure out what is causing this conflict and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure the error you are receiving is due to package conflicts. Typically [signal 11](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/segmentation-fault-on-linux-unix.html) indicates a segmentation fault where a process has attempted to access an invalid memory address or cannot otherwise write correctly. The first things to check is that write permissions are set correctly and you are an using up-to-date version of composer.

If it is due to a package conflict then a quick & easy fix is to be more specific with the package versions specified.

try:

```
"thujohn/analytics": "1.0.*"
```

Also, I notice that you are using a very old version of Laravel Cashier (it's now up to version 5). If possible, switching to a newer version may help.